# Deployement of app (php + Mysql) in Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

I am getting an error message when I give "heroku open" command.

Can any one please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please mention the error message.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.